# Remove table row by finding content with Javascript

Tags: javascript

i have this code:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">X</td>
            <td>X1</td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>        
            <td width="150" align="left">Y</td>
            <td>Y1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td align="left">Status: </td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <select name="status" size="1">
                    <option selected="selected" value="2">one</option>
                    <option value="1">two</option>
                </select>                   
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>        
            <td width="150" align="left">Z</td>
            <td>Z1</td>
        </tr>   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and want to remove with Javascript this line:

```
<tr>    
    <td align="left">Status: </td>
    <td colspan="4">
        <select name="status" size="1">
            <option selected="selected" value="2">one</option>
            <option value="1">two</option>
        </select>                   
    </td>
</tr>
```

the problem is that i don't have any id's or classes for identification.
is there a way to remove the row by searching "Status: " or name="status" with javascript for Firefox only (using it for Greasemonkey)?

i can't use jQuery and i can't edit the code to set any id's

best regards 
bernte

Comment: Will the `tr` tag you want to remove always be the second one? Also, how do you find the `table` element in this markup?

Comment: Also, what browsers do you need to support?

Comment: the tr tag can be also the 5th.. and i'm using it in Greasemonkey for Firefox only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function removeRowByCellValue(table,cellValue) {
    var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("TD");
    for(var x = 0; x < cells.length; x++) {

        // check if cell has a childNode, prevent errors
        if(!cells[x].firstChild) {
            continue;
        }

        if(cells[x].firstChild.nodeValue == cellValue) {
            var row = cells[x].parentNode;
            row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

First get a reference to your table, since you do not have an ID you can use `getElementsByTagName`.. (here i'm assuming that it is the first table in your document)

```
var myTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
```

Then you can invoke the function with the following parameters

```
removeRowByCellValue(myTable,"Status: ");
```

Comment: your script works fine.. but i have 4 html pages and one greasemonkeyscript with different functions! on site one with the status table all works perfect! on site 2 with no status table i receive an error cells[x].firstChild is null.. any ideas?

Comment: please check updated answer, that error probably occurs when the table contains 'empty' cells

Answer (score 5):

If you can afford not being compatible with IE7, You can do that :

```
​var elements = document.querySelectorAll('td[align="left"]');
for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    var text = elements[i].textContent || elements[i].innerText;
    if (text.trim()=='Status:') {
       elements[i].parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(elements[i].parentNode);   
    }
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/kk2NB/)

To be compatible with IE7, you'd probably have to iterate on all rows and cells, which wouldn't really be slower but would be less clear.

Note that I used `trim` which doesn't exist on IE8. To make it work on this browser if needed, you might add this usual fix (from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)) :

```
if(!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
  };
}
```

Comment: This isn't compatible with IE8 and lower because of `.trim()`, and isn't  compatible with any version of Firefox because of `.innerText`.

Comment: +1 for the fixes. I'd personally put `.textContent` before `.innerText` just because it's the standards compliant one, but it'll obviously work either way.

Comment: I'll change it accordingly. But on this very precise topic I don't really get why the standardized name was textContent. Just the one time when it seems that Microsoft picked a pertinent name...

Answer (score 1):

```
var xpathResult = document.evaluate("//td[starts-with(.,'Status:')]", document.body, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
var element = xpathResult.singleNodeValue.parentNode;
while (element.firstChild)
  element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
```

Jsbin http://jsbin.com/urehuw/1/edit

Comment: I think document.evaluate doesn't exist on IE, even IE10.

Comment: Damn you IE!! (shakes fist)

Answer (score 1):

And if you'd like to be compatible with older IE:

```
function closest(el, tag) {
    if (!el || !tag) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return el.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() == tag ? el.parentNode : closest(el.parentNode, tag);
    }
}

// gets all 'select' elements
var sel = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

// iterates through the found 'select' elements
for (var i=0, len = sel.length; i<len; i++) {
    // if the 'select' has the name of 'status'
    if (sel[i].name == 'status') {
        // uses the closest() function to find the ancestor 'tr' element
        var row = closest(sel[i], 'tr');
        // access the 'tr' element's parent to remove the 'tr' child
        row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2jvYD/).

Answer (score 0):

simply use this

```
    var gettag =document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[3] ; // the third tag of tr
         document.removeChild(gettag);
```